# access dynamic query creation in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("Unique_Address1_qry", strSQL)
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

strSQL = "SELECT field1 AS field1, field2 as field2 " & vbCrLf & _
"'" & strScenario & "'" & "AS Scenario, " & vbCrLf & _
"FROM table_tbl " & vbCrLf & _
"GROUP BY field1,....; "
```

The strScenario contains a calculation formula like "[field2]/2+3"
the result is that in every record for the calulated fied, "[field2]/2+3" is showing insted of the calcultion.

Comment: Remove the single quotes `'` around the variable? the `'` is telling the query that it is a literal text string to return.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to repeat what @Comintern said, but I can give you a *fishing rod*:

- Place a breakpoint (<kbd>F9</kbd>) on the line immediately following the `strSQL =` assignment.
- Run the code.
- When execution reaches the breakpoint, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the *immediate pane*, and type:

  ```
  ?strSQL
  ```

This will output the string value (`?` is shorthand for `Print`), which you can then inspect yourself, copy to the clipboard, paste to some new query and try to execute.

Then you can fix the code, move the current line back to the modified `strSQL =` assignment, try `?strSQL` again, rinse & repeat until your code generates a valid SQL query - then you can remove the breakpoint and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to resume execution, and you have working code.

---

> *Give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day. Give a man a fishing rod, he'll eat for the rest of his life.*

Comment: So true. Links for this: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) and [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Answer (score 1):

The query *really* should be parameterized...but you have `strScenario` quoted as a literal.  You're also missing a comma after "field2" and a space after `strScenario`.

It should look more like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT field1 AS field1, field2 as field2, " & _
    strScenario & " AS Scenario FROM table_tbl GROUP BY field1,....; "
```

Note that you can *see* the result of the SQL you build by simply putting `Debug.Print strSQL` after your assignment and looking at it in the Immediate window.

Comment: when I use a simple formula it works, but when I start to using things like : IIF([SumOfVolume]>=5;[SumOfLDM]*1750;0) this gives problems. Is the IIF function that create the isse.

Comment: @Dirk - Look at the result in the immediate window.  Is it valid SQL for MS Access?  In this case, it isn't - `;` terminates a statement - they should be `,`.  If in doubt, copy it into the Access SQL designer and try to execute it.  Access will let you know where your syntax error are.

Comment: I changed the ; with , for the IIF statement and 1,2 into 1.2 and it works. Thx a lot for the help. :-)